# Nginx one alias for multiple location directives

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have installed a project in a separate directory to make this project available on multiple domains

```
location ^~ /phpRedisAdmin/css/ {

        alias /home/phpRedisAdmin/css/;
}

location ^~ /phpRedisAdmin/js/ {

        alias /home/phpRedisAdmin/js/;
}

location ^~ /phpRedisAdmin/images/ {

        alias /home/phpRedisAdmin/images/;
}
```

To prevent declaring a location directive for each one of the project subdirectory, is it possible to declare one location directive that would handle all the possible aliases instead?

I am looking for something like this (I don't know how to retrieve in the alias directive what is in the parenthesis):

```
location ^~ /phpRedisAdmin/(css|images|js)/ {

        alias /home/phpRedisAdmin/>> what should I insert here? <</;
}
```

**Problem solved, I ended up using this solution**:

```
location ^~ /phpRedisAdmin/(css|images|js)$ {
    alias /home/phpRedisAdmin/$1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use an `alias` directive, where a `root` directive will suffice. One solution would be to define a `location` block for all URIs which live below `/phpRedisAdmin`. For example:

```
location ^~ /phpRedisAdmin/ {
    root /home;

    location ~ \.php$ { 
        ... 
    }
}
```

If you need to execute PHP scripts within this `location`, add a nested location (as shown above).

If you must use a regular expression `location` with an `alias`, you will need to capture the **entire** remainder of the URI. For example:

```
location ^~ /phpRedisAdmin/((?:css|images|js)/.*)$ {
    alias /home/phpRedisAdmin/$1;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below

```
   location ~* /phpRedisAdmin/(?P<folder>css|images|js)/ {
        alias /home/phpRedisAdmin/$folder;
    }
```